# Required delayed_job example that is not for sending mails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, delayed-job

Trying to get delayed_job working. I want to do a http post to another server without blocking my rails app. I figured delayed_job would be a good idea. However I am not able to get it to work.

Primarily in the controller if I hit a condition I want to do a http post to a known server. 
What I have not understood so far is

1. Can I delay a function defined in the controller itself?
2. Do i need to define a separate class and have the function there which I can then include in the controller?

Steps so far:

- Added gem 'delayed_job_active_record' to Gem file
- Added gem "daemons" also
- rails generate delayed_job:upgrade
- rake db:migrate
- ran RAILS_ENV=development script/delayed_job start

Then execute the code.
Code in the controller:

Attempt 1: # Leads to  NoMethodError (undefined method `post_to_server` for SimpleObjectForTestController )

```
class SimpleObjectForTestController 
 def create
  ....
  if( some condition )
    SimpleObjectForTestController.delay.post_to_server
  end
  ....
 end
 def post_to_server
     Typhoeus::Request.post( "http://127.0.0.1:4567/hi", :body => $fixed_config )
 end
end
```

Attempt 2: Also gives same error now with SeperatedClass

```
 class SeperatedClass
    def post_to_server
       Typhoeus::Request.post( "http://127.0.0.1:4567/hi", :body => $fixed_config )
    end
 end
 class SimpleObjectForTestController
  def create
    ....
    if( some condition )
       SeperatedClass.delay.post_to_server
    end
    ....
  end
end
```

Some other context:
This is a non UI application. 
Using Rails 3.2.6
Ruby 1.9.2
Using delayed_job (3.0.3) 
Using delayed_job_active_record (0.3.2)

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `post_to_server` is a instance method.
This should work:

```
def self.post_to_server
  ...
end
```

Comment: Worked. Also had to put it in the model and not the controller.